# Asymptotics of $(6^n-1000)/(2^n+1)$

Tags: asymptotics

If $f(n) = 5n^2 + 3n + 7$ can be written as $\Theta(n^2)$, then how to write the following in $\Theta$-notation:
$$ \frac{6^n - 1000}{2^n + 1}. $$

Comment: Let me guide you on the path by asking: what do you need to divide this expression, so, that the limit becomes a finite number ?

Comment: is it (1/2^n)???

Comment: "Almost". Use $3 $ in place of $2$.

Comment: Just divide the numerator by (1/3^n) so that the expression becomes factor of 2^n?

Comment: When you divide on $3^n$, then you'll have limit $1$, so..

Comment: Please don't edit your question to remove part of its content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each (eventually positive) function is its own $\Theta$; so if you denote your function by $g(n)$, then certainly $g(n) = \Theta(g(n))$.

Usually, what we mean by finding the $\Theta$-complexity of a function $g(n)$ is finding a *simple* function $h(n)$ such that $g(n) = \Theta(h(n))$. In your case, it is not hard to check that $g(n) = \Theta(3^n)$. Indeed, for large $n$ we have $6^n - 1000 \approx 6^n$ and $2^n + 1 \approx 2^n$, hence your expression is roughly equal to $6^n/2^n = 3^n$. This can be made more precise:
$$
\frac{6^n - 1000}{2^n + 1} \sim 3^n,
$$
in the sense that the ratio of both expressions tends to $1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $n\to \infty$ you are free to show
$$\frac{6^n - 1000}{2^n + 1}$$
as

$$\Theta\left(\left(\frac{6}{2}\right)^n\right)$$

that means

$$\Theta\left(\left(3\right)^n\right).$$